# Creating four frames using HTML

Tags: html

I need to create four frames in an HTML document. The code below creates only three frames.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<FRAMESET cols="100%" rows="10%,90%" >
  <FRAMESET rows="100%,">
      <FRAME src="frame_a.htm">
  </FRAMESET>
  <FRAMESET cols="20%,60%" rows="40%,80">
      <FRAME src="frame_b.htm">
      <FRAME src="frame_c.htm">
  </FRAMESET>
  <FRAMESET rows="60%," >
      <FRAME src="frame_d.htm">
  </FRAMESET>

</FRAMESET>
</html>
```

This snapshot explains the question. Notice that the above code didn't create frame D.

[image]

Comment: @ThiefMaster My thoughts exactly.

Comment: Thanks @ThiefMaster. What is the alternative?

Comment: Using server-side scripting to merge those files and using CSS to display everything in a proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the two top rows take up 100% of the height, and you haven't specificed any height for the third.

Try:

```
<FRAMESET cols="100%" rows="10%,40%,50%">
```

Answer (score 0):

`<FRAMESET cols="100%" rows="10%,90%">` creates a frameset with two frames: The first one with 10%, the second one with 90%. Since you want three rows you need to add a third value.